# What happened to /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: networking

I installed updates to 20.04 and all my interfaces.d scripts are gone, and /etc/network/interfaces is also gone. Even if I recreate it NetworkManager doesn't stop controlling the interfaces. Did /etc/network/interfaces get deprecated or something?

Please...please...don't tell me I'm forced to use NetworkManager because it's a real dogpile for anything but an auto wifi interface.

Comment: Well, for others `/etc/network/interfaces` is the dogpile.

Comment: This was deprecated many, many years ago. NetPlan/CloudInit has been the default for quite some time 

Comment: I didnt know interfaces was part of ifupdown pkg. I find interfaces so easy/simple. I can't get a NetMan profile to stick, it always ignores it and goes auto-config if I merely blow on it. It works for my wifi fine. I've looked at Netplan and I like where it's headed. I appreciate the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I installed ifupdown and I have interfaces back.

```
sudo apt install ifupdown
```

Thanks @muru for that link.